# Geopoint Long and Lat represented as int, but Long and Lat fields in MediaStore represented as doubles?

Tags: android, types, geolocation

I am confused with the data types of these fields.  I want to get the long and lat of an image stored on the phone and represent it as a Geopoint.  My code to do this is:

```
double long_ = imageCursor.getDouble(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE));
double lat = imageCursor.getDouble(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE));
```

The confusion arises because these are float values, but the Geopoint constructor takes long and lat as int types.  Is there some conversion I must do manually?

Comment: -> Most likely one developer wanted to be precise with int and another didn't think about that as floats and doubles are 'not' exact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some conversion I must do manually?

Yes. Quoting [the documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html), `GeoPoint` is "an immutable class representing a pair of latitude and longitude, stored as **integer numbers of microdegrees**".

The rest of Android, including `MediaStore`, hold latitude and longitude as floating-point values in degrees, not integer values in microdegrees. When you create your GeoPoint, you will need to do the conversion. I use a utility method like this:

```
  private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
    return(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1000000.0), (int)(lon*1000000.0)));
  }
```